# How can I unzip a multipart ZIP file on Windows made on a Mac

Tags: windows, mac, zip

I created a big zip file in three parts on my Mac:

stuff.z01
stuff.z02
stuff.z03

I used the terminal zip command for this.

How can I unzip these on my Windows machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a free application like [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to unzip it. First, install application then `Right click` on file -> `7-zip` -> `Open Archive`.

Then double-click on the file inside the dialogue box and wait for the load to be complete then press `extract`. Should work like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `copy` command to combine them on Windows:

**Command Prompt**

```
copy /b stuff.z* stuff.zip
```

**PowerShell**

```
& cmd.exe /c copy /b .\stuff.z* .\stuff.zip
```

The easiest way to extract the resulting archive to use the *Extract All* context menu option in the Explorer UI. Alternately, you can use PowerShell as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768303/how-to-unzip-a-file-in-powershell#27771099), Shell automation via command prompt as in [this example](https://superuser.com/questions/1314420/how-to-unzip-a-file-using-the-cmd?rq=1), or a third-party solution like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org). The latter of which will also recombine archives for extraction IIRC.