# How to unzip a file using the cmd?

Tags: windows, command-line, zip

I want to make a BAT file that will ZIP or UNZIP a file. For zipping a file, I have found this question:
[Can you zip a file from the command prompt using ONLY Windows' built-in capability to zip files?](https://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili/112094)

The answers given there are great and working for me, but I couldn't find any information about how to unzip the files. Like in the link, I can't assume any third-party tools (except winRAR).

Thanks ahead and sorry for English mistakes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26843122/4568534 This answer shows yoyu how to unzip a file

Comment: if you have PowerShell 5 (builtin in Windows 10) then you could use `powershell -command "Expand-Archive C:\foo\bar.zip C:\somewhere"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create .zip folder from the command line - (Windows)](https://superuser.com/questions/201371/create-zip-folder-from-the-command-line-windows)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This batch file code will help you to unzip a file.

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
Call :UnZipFile "C:\Temp\" "c:\FolderName\batch.zip"
exit /b

:UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <newzipfile>
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
>%vbs%  echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>>%vbs% echo If NOT fso.FolderExists(%1) Then
>>%vbs% echo fso.CreateFolder(%1)
>>%vbs% echo End If
>>%vbs% echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
>>%vbs% echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(%2).items
>>%vbs% echo objShell.NameSpace(%1).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
>>%vbs% echo Set fso = Nothing
>>%vbs% echo Set objShell = Nothing
cscript //nologo %vbs%
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
```

**N.B.** C:\Temp is folder where it stores the Extracted (UnZip) File.

And,  c:\FolderName\batch.zip is source path, (where Zip files are stored).

*Please, Change the Full File Path ( Drive, Folder & Zip file name), according to your need.*

Comment: Seems like he just copied it from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704041/creating-batch-script-to-unzip-a-file-without-additional-zip-tools . Shouldn't this answer be reported for plagarism, because he is not referencing the original source.

Answer (score 129):

On Windows 10 build 17063 or later you can use `tar.exe` (similar to the *nix one). This is also available in the nanoserver docker container

```
C:\> tar -xf archive.zip
```

*Note: zip support is not well documented*

ref: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdtar&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+5.3-stable

Comment: Luckily, it’s `bsdtar`. Because `.zip` is not GZip (`-z`).

Comment: It does work well with .gz and .zip

Comment: Yes. Because it ignores the incorrect `-z` argument and always uses autodetection.

Comment: Thanks, I removed it. I thought that with `-z` is to call the gzip submodule, which in turn does the autodetect.

Comment: It works perfectly for me on `Windows 10`. 
FYI: I am using the `tar` command from GNU `CoreUtils for Windows` http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

Comment: After reading `tar --help`, the support for `.zip` files seems totally undocumented and also unexpected to me. Maybe it's worth mentioning this in the answer text..

Comment: since it claims to be a bsdtar it is documented here https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdtar&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+5.3-stable
however many options are missing though

Comment: be careful with this as it will overwrite existing files with no indication at all. `-k` can apparently be used to not overwrite, but haven't tried it. (also note that `tar --help` has more detailed help than `tar /?`)

Comment: the -C switch can be added to send the extracted files to some location e.g. `C:\> tar -xf archive.zip -C some\directory` although this may not work with Windows drive letters or UNC paths.

Answer (score 50):

If you have Windows 10, you can use the much shorter Powershell equivalent

```
Expand-Archive -Force C:\path\to\archive.zip C:\where\to\extract\to
```

Comment: What about older windows version?

Comment: You just need Powershell v5.0+

Answer (score 12):

If you have Windows 10 (and powershell), but still want to unzip from within `.bat`/`.cmd`-file (cmd.exe), you can use

```
powershell -command "Expand-Archive -Force '%~dp0my_zip_file.zip' '%~dp0'"
```

where `my_zip_file.zip` is the file to be unzipped and `%~dp0` points to the same folder are where the `.bat`/`.cmd`-file  is (Change the folder, if needed).

Comment: I have two problems with this. spawning a powershell takes prohibitively long (about 20 seconds in my test), and it can't even extract a zip file with another extension.

Comment: There is no powershell in some nano containers for example. Not a valuable answer ...

Comment: Nothing in the question mentions that it needs to run in a nano container. Very useful answer for me

Answer (score 2):

```
ZipFile="C:\Users\spvaidya\Music\folder.zip"
ExtractTo="C:\Users\spvaidya\Music\"




'If the extraction location does not exist create it.

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If NOT fso.FolderExists(ExtractTo) Then



 fso.CreateFolder(ExtractTo)

End If

'Extract the contants of the zip file.

set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).items

objShell.NameSpace(ExtractTo).CopyHere(FilesInZip)

Set fso = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
```

The following vbscript can be saved as file.vbs and then run using batch script like:

```
file.vbs
```

save this in .bat file and run it.

Answer (score 2):

I use this one-liner to extract all zip files in the current path to their own subdirectory based on their file name:

```
gci -Recurse -Filter *.zip |ForEach-Object {Expand-Archive -Path $_.Fullname -DestinationPath $_.BaseName -Force}
```

Comment: Question clearly states `cmd` and you gave a `powershell` command

Comment: Very helpful if you're on Windows

Answer (score 1):

To unzip all files in the current directory in one command, using Powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem *.zip | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath .\Extracted -Force
```